# Are lambdas allowed in dictionary comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have the following:

```
>>> {c: (lambda: c) for c in ["A","B"]}["A"]()
'B'
```

when I expect the result to be `'A'`.

Note that

```
>>> {c: c for c in ["A","B"]}["A"]
'A'
```

Are lambdas not allowed in dictionary comprehensions or have I screwed up the syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowed"? There is a *surprising* value, but it is not an *error*

Answer (score 1):

There's one object created by the lambda, and the value that it captures is modified during each element of the comprehension

It is the same as if you did

```
class Lambda:
    def set(self, value):
        self.value = value;
        return self
    def __call__(self):
        return value

lam = Lambda()
{c: lam.set(c) for c in ["A","B"]}["A"]()
```

Each entry in the dictionary has the same value, `lam`, that returns the last `set` value.